# How can I fit two semivariograms in one plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, statistics, geostatistics

I tried to plot two semivariogram in one plot but unfortunately it does not work.
I guess the solution is pretty easy but I am at the end of my latin.

This ist the code of the variograms I want to put in one plot together:

```
variog_iso_a1 <- fit.variogram(  emp_variog_iso_a1,
                                         vgm(  psill = 2000,
                                               model = "Sph",
                                               range = 200,
                                               nugget = 500))
        
        plot(emp_variog_iso_a1, variog_iso_a1, as.table=TRUE, main = "Acker H1 C_org", plot.numbers=T)


variog_iso_a2 <- fit.variogram(  emp_variog_iso_a2,
                                         vgm(  psill = 2000,
                                               model = "Sph",
                                               range = 200,
                                               nugget = 500))
        
        plot(emp_variog_iso_a2, variog_iso_a2, as.table=TRUE, main = "Acker H2 C_org", plot.numbers=T)
```

Secondly I would also like to plot two semivariogram in one plot but with a second y-axis on the right side because of the different values.

```
variog_iso_a1 <- fit.variogram(  emp_variog_iso_a1,
                                         vgm(  psill = 2000,
                                               model = "Sph",
                                               range = 200,
                                               nugget = 500))
        
        plot(emp_variog_iso_a1, variog_iso_a1, as.table=TRUE, main = "Acker H1 C_org", plot.numbers=T)


variog_iso_l1 <- fit.variogram(  emp_variog_iso_l1,
                                         vgm(  psill = 2000,
                                               model = "Sph",
                                               range = 200,
                                               nugget = 500))
        
        plot(emp_variog_iso_l1, variog_iso_l1, as.table=TRUE, main = "Acker H1 Lichtwert", plot.numbers=T)
```

I was only able two show the points of each variogram but not with the model fitted inside. This is the code I tried but does not work!

```
plot(emp_variog_iso_a1$dist, emp_variog_iso_a1$gamma, ylim=c(0,2500))
        points(emp_variog_iso_a2$dist, emp_variog_iso_a2$gamma, col = "red", add=T, labels=emp_variog_iso_a2$np)
        
        
        plot(emp_variog_iso_a1$dist, emp_variog_iso_a1$gamma, ylim=c(0,2500),main="Semivarianz Lichtwert und organische Substanz Horizont 1 Ackerland", ylab = "Semivarianz", xlab = "Distanz" )
        par(new = TRUE)
        plot(emp_variog_iso_l1$dist, emp_variog_iso_l1$gamma, col = "red", labels=emp_variog_iso_l1$np )
        
        points(emp_variog_iso_l1$dist, emp_variog_iso_l1$gamma, col = "red", add=T, labels=emp_variog_iso_l1$np, yaxt = "n")
        
        plot(emp_variog_iso_a2$dist, emp_variog_iso_a2$gamma, ylim=c(0,2500),main="Semivarianz Lichtwert und organische Substanz Horizont 2 Ackerland", ylab = "Semivarianz", xlab = "Distanz" )
        points(emp_variog_iso_l2$dist, emp_variog_iso_l2$gamma, col = "red", add=T, labels=emp_variog_iso_l2$np)
```

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: It would help if you could post an example of your desired output.

Comment: @Caddisfly i am not allowed to post a picture. But generally it is a line model (spheric) and points through the model pretty similar to regression

Comment: Well, you are unlikely to get any help without a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use `variogramLine()` for this:

```
VL=variogramLine(YourVariogramFit, maxdist = ...)
```

next, add it to your plot with `lines()`

```
lines(VL)
```